# Where error happened? exec(compile(script,"<string>",'exec'))

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, traceback

I have 2 files. In one of them the script (calling the function from another file) is compiled and executed. What I need is to identify where the error occurred: whether it was an error in creating a script (in which line of the script) in the user_script.py or it was error in the foo(parameter) function.

I want to catch any errors (SyntaxError, TypeError, etc) and handle them differently depending on whether it occurred in the script itself or in the function foo(parameter)

I show two examples with NameError but in principle I want to do the same with any type of errors. To which attributes should I refer to distinguish them?

Example 1

**user_script.py**

```
import sys
import traceback
from Catch_errors.my_function import function

script="a=1\nb=3\nfunction.foo(c)"
exec(compile(script,"<string>",'exec'))
```

**my_function.py**

```
class function:
    def foo(parameter):
        a = parameter
        print(a)  # or e.g. causing the error print(a+'sss')
```

**Output:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 4.0\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 2199, in <module>
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 4.0\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1638, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 4.0\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc) 
  File "C:/Users/Support/PycharmProjects/HelloWorldProject/Catch_errors/user_Script.py", line 7, in <module>
    exec(compile(script,"<string>",'exec'))
  File "<string>", line 3, in <module>
NameError: name 'c' is not defined
```

Example 2

**user_script.py**

```
import sys
import traceback
from Catch_errors.my_function import function

script="a=1\nb=3\nfunction.foo(2)"
exec(compile(script,"<string>",'exec'))
```

**my_function.py**

```
class function:
    def foo(parameter):
        a = parameter
        print(b)
```

**Output:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 4.0\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 2199, in <module>
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 4.0\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1638, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 4.0\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc) 
  File "C:/Users/Support/PycharmProjects/HelloWorldProject/Catch_errors/user_Script.py", line 5, in <module>
    script="a=1\nb=3\nfunction.foo("+b+")"
NameError: name 'b' is not defined
```

Comment: Also, it would help if you post exactly your error.

Comment: No, what you suggest is wrong. It causes TypeError, whereas my version works properly. 

However, I am not searching the way to create correct scripts, but rather want to catch any possible errors user could do. I want to catch any errors (SyntaxError, TypeError, etc) and handle them differently depending on whether it occurred in the script itself or in the function `foo(parameter)`

Comment: If your `script` didn't compile, you'd get a `SyntaxError`. Showing us the actual traceback would let us help you far better however.

Comment: You'd have to introspect the traceback to determine where in the stack the exception took place.

Comment: I think my suggestion wasn't wrong. I just didnt notice the second mistake in your code (first being calling class variable without parenthesis after class name, second was missing `\n`. 

I would also suggest that you include "_but rather want to catch any possible errors user could do. I want to catch any errors (SyntaxError, TypeError, etc) and handle them differently depending on whether it occurred in the script itself or in the function foo(parameter)_" in your post, instead of the comments.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I have updated the post. Do you know which attributes I could check?

Comment: in e.g.1 in `user_script.py` file -   chnage `script="a=1\nb=3\nfunction.foo("+b+")"` to `script="a=1\nb=3\nfunction.foo(b)"`  because 'b` is define in the script.

Comment: in e.g 2 in `my_function.py` file. change `print(b)` to `print(a)`

Comment: @VivekSable I have a question to you. Have you ever heard about error handling? I don't ask to correct mistakes in the code, I make them on purpose to simulate the error which I want to catch and handle in appropriate manner. (https://wiki.python.org/moin/HandlingExceptions )

Comment: Ok got it now. Can we just add `exec(..` code inside `try except` block

Comment: Very nice. Someone keeps minusing the question without suggesting something. All the answers have nothing to do yet with the question asked. I have added the new one. With `traceback.extract_tb(sys.exc_info()[-1])` I can get information about file name where the error happened. This still has to be tested. Structure of returned list differs depending on the type of exception catched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import sys, traceback
from Catch_errors.my_function import function

script = "a=1\nb=3\nfunction().foo(a)"

try:
    compiled_script = compile(script,"<string>",'exec')
    exec(compiled_script)
except:
    exc_type, exc_obj, exc_tb = sys.exc_info()
    tr = traceback.extract_tb(sys.exc_info()[-1])
    print(tr)
    if "my_function.py" in tr[-1][0]:
        print("EXCEPTION IN FUNCTION "+str(tr[-1][-2])+"(), line '"+tr[-1][-1]+"'.")
        print(exc_obj.args[0])
    else:
        print('EXCEPTION IN USER SCRIPT: {}'.format(exc_obj))
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to make function.foo a static method.

```
class function:
    @staticmethod
    def foo(parameter):
        a = parameter
        print(a)  # or e.g. causing the error print(a+'sss')
```

Comment: Which attributes should I refer then? What exactly changes for my case when I make it static?

Comment: @Spu: two change need 1. \n was missing in script="a=1\nb=3\nfunction.foo(2)" statement. 2. by static method.   see my solution for more information.

Comment: @vivek-sable the last "\n" is really unnecessary, have you ever tested it?

Comment: @huazhihao I have no problems with accessing the method. My question is about correct way for error handling. I have updated the post.

Answer (score 0):

1. `\n` was missing in `script="a=1\nb=3\nfunction.foo(2)"` statement.
2. By static method: Use static method to call static function. `className.FunctionName()`.
3. By class metohd: Create class method e.g. `foo1()` and call by class instance e.g. ClassName().FunctionName()

test.py

```
import sys
import traceback
from test1 import function

script="a=1\nb=3\nfunction.foo(2)"  # of e.g. script="a=1\nb=3\function.foo(2, 3)" 
try:exec(compile(script,"<string>",'exec'))
except:print traceback.format_exc()

script="a=1\nb=3\nfunction().foo1(33)"  # of e.g. script="a=1\nb=3\function.foo(2, 3)" 
try:exec(compile(script,"<string>",'exec'))
except:print traceback.format_exc()

script="a=1\nb=3\nfunction().foo1(c)" 
try:exec(compile(script,"<string>",'exec'))
except NameError, e:
    print "NameError exception, ", traceback.format_exc()
except:
    print traceback.format_exc()
```

test1.py

```
class function:
    @staticmethod
    def foo( parameter):
        a = parameter
        print "in foo:", a  # or e.g. causing the error print(a+'sss')

    def foo1(self, parameter):
        a = parameter
        print "in foo1:", a   # or e.g. causing the error print(a+'sss')
```

output:

```
$ python test.py 
in foo: 2
in foo1: 3
NameError exception,  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1527, in <module>
    try:exec(compile(script,"<string>",'exec'))
  File "<string>", line 3, in <module>
NameError: name 'c' is not defined
```

Comment: Thank you, that's useful, but doesn't help anyhow my main problem. Do you know how to differentiate between errors in the script and errors in the function?

Comment: you are trying to access `foo` method which is define in the class. In my @Spu: solution you can see difference between `foo` and `foo1` method. if you want to call `foo` method then you have to make it static method and call from class name. And if you want to call `foo1` then you need to create instance of class and then call.

Comment: I have no problems with accessing the method. My question is about correct way for error handling. I have updated the post.

Comment: see my comment for both examples.

Comment: @Spu: now `c` is not define. What you are trying?